# How to load an image with jquery after clicking a button and get data with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can't find a way to load an image before getting my data. Practiclly what I want to do is:

1. click a button
2. display a loading image
3. after 2 second the loading image should disapear
4. after the image is out display my text

This is my code. I change it so many times that i don't know if is still good

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libreria/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[name=campo1]").click(function(){
                function imagen(){
                    $("#imagen").css("display", "block") ;
                    setTimeout(imagen, 2000);
                }

                var ajax = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url : 'datos.txt',
                    /*beforeSend: function(){
                    });*/
                });

                ajax.done(function(data){            
                    $("div").html(data);
                });

                ajax.fail(function(data){
                    alert("No se ha podido cargar el archivo");
                });
            });
        });         
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img id="imagen" src="images/loader.gif" style="display:none"> 
    </div> 
    <input type="button" name="campo1" value="Traer fichero de texto"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you actually want to wait 2 seconds, or do you want to do it as soon as the AJAX call has finished?

Comment: What about to set a 2-seconds timeout on ajax?

Comment: I want to display the loading image for 2 seconds.

Comment: Perhaps a more important question is why do you want to display a "Loading" image for 2 seconds when your asynchronous operation only takes "1 millisecond"?   I agree with Phillip G's approach with showing the loading image ONLY while you're actually waiting.  Please don't make the user wait for an arbitrary amount of time without reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libreria/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[name=campo1]").click(function(){
                $("#imagen").show();
                var ajax = $.ajax({
                              type: "GET",
                              url : 'datos.txt',
                              success : function(data){
                                    $("#imagen").hide();
                                    $("div").html(data);
                              },
                              error: function(){
                                    $("#imagen").hide();
                                    alert("No se ha podido cargar el archivo");
                              }
                           });
            });
        });         
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img id="imagen" src="images/loader.gif" style="display:none"> 
    </div> 
    <input type="button" name="campo1" value="Traer fichero de texto"/>
</body>

</html>
```

By doing this, your loader image will show before you make your ajax call and disapear once completed. If en error has occured eg. the call fails: an alert is shown!

**EDIT**
If you really want the loading pic to disapear after 2 secounds you could remove all `$("#imagen").hide()`, and paste this after `$("#imagen").show()`. But i would disencurage you from doing that since the ajax request could take considerably longer time then that!

```
$("#imagen").show();

setTimeout(function(){
              $("#imagen").hide();
           },2000);

var ajax = $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url : 'datos.txt',
                  success : function(data){
                                           $("div").html(data);
                  },
                  error: function(){
                                    alert("No se ha podido cargar el archivo");
                              }
                });
```

One additional problem, that probably may be One of your conserns is that you are replacing the image with the loaded content. Since the image is in the same div that you place your data into. Try using `$("div").append(data)` instead of `.html(data)` Or move your image outside the div.

Comment: In my prefered version: Thats because thats all the time needed for the ajax call to finish, But if you try the example I edited in, it will workm showing the image for 2 secounds.

Comment: I did that to but i only get a blink of the loading image! 
This is what do you mean, right? 
`$("#imagen").show();   
   var ajax = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : 'datos.txt',
     success: function(data){ 
       setTimeout(function(){ 
                                    $("#imagen").hide();
                                },2000);   
      $("div").html(data);
     }, 
     error: function(){
       setTimeout(function(){ 
                                    $("#imagen").hide();
                               },2000);
      alert("No se ha podido cargar el archivo"); 
     }
   });`

Comment: No! See my new edit. That is what i mean. Also: you are replacing your image with your content.

Comment: I think the problem is with the click button! For example: if I put the `$("#imagen").show();
  setTimeout(function(){
              $("#imagen").hide();
           },2000); ` before doing click it works else it doesn't. Thank you anyway

Comment: The problem is certinly not your button. Read my post again. Espacially the edit!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to display the loading image onclick and hide the loading image on success of the call, not a timeout.

Here's a example:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  // Show the spinner after the user clicks
  $("#imagen").show();

  $.ajax({url:"datos.txt",success:function(result){
    // Hide the spinner on success of the call
    $("#imagen").hide();
    // Put the returned data into your element
    $("div").html(result);
  }});
});
```

You don't want to use a timer for a spinner as sometimes asynchronous calls can take a long time. You want to display a loading indicator for the actual duration of the load.

I hope this makes sense.